# How do I copy my database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I am working on visual studio 2010 and i have a database in Server Explorer that i can see that is not in the App_data in the solution explorer.. I need to copy it somewhere to upload it to the host..

I think the database is suitable for SQL server2005 , cause that is the only sql server version installed on my computer with the vs2010.

Here are my connection string:

```
<add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True" />
```

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio? This is much easier to copy a website in.

Comment: I do have SQL Server Management Studio 2005.. Look at the connection string..this is how the Database that i named is called: dima-00aa1da557.model.dbo

Comment: Without sql server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35479710/2901207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can back up the database by right click on db and choose back up. Restore it on your host /web server.

Comment: Yup thats the answer...Thats what i did

Comment: you can also use data comparison if that suits your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35479710/2901207

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to export you database schema and mandatory data as sql scripts using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) then  run the script on the host.

Here is a great tutorial about it http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

EDIT: if you are using VS2010 there is a new feature in the deployment called "Package/Publish SQL" allow you to package your SQL DB. Here is a tutorial how to use it http://rachelappel.com/deployment/database-deployment-with-the-vs-2010-package-publish-database-tool/

Answer (score 1):

Erm. your connection string says the database in use is model. That's a special database in SQL Server that's used a template for new databases (that's why you can't detach/copy). You're going to have all sorts of problems if you stick with that name.

But DO NOT rename it. You're going to have to create a new database - which will have everything you've put in model in it. Then remove everything you've added to model.

You should now be able to detach your new database and move it elsewhere.

Comment: Well spotted, I didn't notice the database name

Comment: I found a way,, i backed up the "model" and restored it,,then i attached it..it worked!!!

Comment: You still need to clean up your model database as each new database will contain everything you put in model.

Answer (score 0):

Select you database in SQL Managment Studio.Then Tasks\Detach. 
After this you can copy the database files to another distination. To make you database on-line again, just do  Tasks\Attach.

P.S It's only the one among other approaches to accomplish your task.

Comment: In task , i have only the option of Back up :(

Comment: You can't detach the model database. it's a system database