# Copy table from one database to other using visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, copy-paste

I have been unable to install SQL server management studio on my PC, let me say if I do not want to do as well, then, is there a way to

**copy database table form one database to other using visual studio  without sql management studio?** I can copy but finding nowhere the option to paste it on target database

I have created table with same structure in target_databse so I need a query like

```
Insert Into target_Database.dbo.dishes (id, name,price)
Select id,name,price From source_Database.dbo.dishes
```

Or any wizard provided by visual studio?

I have tried to Data Compare but unable to connect the source_database there.

Comment: >>unable to connect the source_database there. ? I expect its a connection issue. not the tool issue. Try with Red Gate SQL Data Compare.

Comment: If anyone is still looking for this, here is the answer I just wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35479710/2901207

Answer (score 0):

You can also use osql or sqlcmd command line tools for manipulating with your databases.

Comment: osql -SYourServerName -E.   Often your server name is .\SQLEXRESS